# configure couchbase xdcr with ddos protection

Tags: couchbase, database-replication

Because xdcr is used over the internet, it is totally possible to perform ddos attacks on those xdcr ports?

Should I do something about it? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

XDCR ports only need to be open to the other cluster nodes; so if you did use XDCR over the open internet you would typically firewall those ports to only be accessible to the remote cluster.

(Note: You would likely want to use encryption of your data if you are doing XDCR over the internet, either using XDCR-with-SSL in Couchbase 2.5 or otherwise with a VPN tunnel / private WAN.

Comment: By using firewall on those ports we can prevent ddos? I thought those ports still can be flooded?

Comment: I think firewalled those ports will not help in ddos prevention or protection. Read that firewall is not meant for that.

Comment: Firewalls are not designed to handle DDoS attacks, unfortunately. See http://blog.radware.com/security/2013/05/can-firewall-and-ips-block-ddos-attacks/